# Customizing Devise gem (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to add a new field "registration code" along with the email/password in sign up form. (i have the registration code field in a separate database, only a valid registration code/email pair will have to work with the sign up)

I could not able to find any controller for actions done by devise gem.

How do i customize devise to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your question basically has nothing to do with Devise itself (besides the views). To validate your registration code/email pairs, you surely need to add this as validation.

The easy way to validate registration code could be:

```
class User
  validate :validate_registration_code

  private
  def validate_registration_code
    reg_code =  RegistrationCode.find_by_code(registration_code)
    unless reg_code.email == record.email
      errors.add(:registration_code, "Invalid registration code for #{record.email}")
    end
  end
end
```

You also might want to write simple custom validator:

```
class RegistrationCodeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    # actual reg code validation
    # might look like:
    reg_code =  RegistrationCode.find_by_code(record.registration_code)
    unless reg_code.email == record.email
      record.errors[:registration_code] << "Invalid registration code for #{record.email}"
    end
  end
end

# in your User model
class User
  # include registration code validator
  include RegistrationCodeValidator
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```

Comment: Thanks Goshakkk.. it works just like that..
Also i have learnt ways to use the Model like this..
Thanks again..!!!

Comment: No problems :) Glad that my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

Devise keeps it's controllers behind the scenes inside the gem. If you want to add an action or modify one, you have to subclass it and do a little work in routes to get the action to your controller.

However you shouldn't need to do that to add a field. See goshakkk's answer